# Remove space before slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, slideshow

I have slideshow and aside content in html.

I want to remove the space below the slideshow so that the aside content will be just near the end of the slideshow.

I dont know how to remove the space.

If I give margin, slideshow gets disturbed. What should I need to add ?

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/F9c6S/3/

How can i do this ?

```
<div class="skdslider">
    <ul id="demo1" class="slides">
<li>
<img src="slides/1.jpg" />
<!--Slider Description example-->
 <div class="slide-desc">
        <h2>Slider Title 1</h2>
        <p>Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. <a class="more" href="#">more</a></p>
  </div>
</li>
<li><img src="slides/2.jpg" />
   <div class="slide-desc">
        <h2>Slider Title 2</h2>
        <p>Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. <a class="more" href="#">more</a></p>
  </div>
</li>
<li><img src="slides/3.jpeg" />
<!--NO Description Here-->
</li>
<li><img src="slides/4.jpg" />
  <div class="slide-desc">
        <h2>Slider Title 4</h2>
        <p>Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. <a class="more" href="#">more</a></p>
  </div>
</li>
<li><img src="slides/5.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="slides/6.jpg" />
  <div class="slide-desc">
        <h2>Slider Title 6</h2>
        <p>Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. Demo description here. <a class="more" href="#">more</a></p>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<aside class="top-sidebar">

        <article>
            <h2>DEMO</h2>
            <p><li>DEMO</li>
            <li>DEMO</li>
            <li>DEMO</li>
            <li>DEMO</li></p>
        </article>
    </aside>

    <aside class="top-sidebar">
        <article>
            <h2>DEMO</h2>
            <p>
            <li>DEMO</li>
            <li>IDEMO</li>
            <li>DEMO</li>
            <li>DEMO</li></p>
        </article>
    </aside>

    <aside class="top-sidebar">
        <article>
            <h2>DEMO</h2>
            <p><li>DEMO</li>
            <li>DEMO</li>
            <li>DEMO</li>

</p>
        </article>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove padding for

```
.skdslider:after {
    content: '';
    /* padding-top: 50%; */ 
    display: block;
}
```

And give min-height to

```
.skdslider{
 width:100%;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow:hidden;
 min-height: 558px; /**For have space for slider**/
}
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F9c6S/7/)

Comment: Can you give version of firefox.

Comment: 27.0.1 version of firefox

Comment: Actually the images are displayed outside of the slide content

Comment: Try giving overflow: hidden to .skdslider

Comment: Its not working @Tushar. Slideshow is not working for firefox. I noticed it just goes after the full width of the site i.e., to the right of the full width. If I give overflow:hidden, slideshow not working.

Comment: Using min-height stops the slider from being responsive.

Answer (score 1):

The gap between the bottom of the slider and your `aside` element is caused by the top margin on the `h2` element contained within your `aside` element. To fix this, you can simply:

```css
aside h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

The large gap at the bottom of your slider is caused by this styling:

```css
.skdslider:after {
    ...
    padding-top: 50%;
}
```

To fix that, remove that `padding-top` completely, and add:

```css
.skdslider {
    height: ...;
}
```

You'll have to determine how high you want your slider to be, so replace that `...` with whatever you desire.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9c6S/6/).

Comment: Images not working in firefox. But the space as you said is working well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `max-height` to the `skdslider` style: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9c6S/5/) this should remove that extra white space.

```
.skdslider
{
     width:100%;
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     overflow:hidden;
    max-height: 403px;
}
```